# Не работает загрузка файлов через php форму

Tags: php, html, формы

Помогите пожалуйста, не работает форма загрузки файлов:

```
<form action="forms.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Описание:<br> <textarea rows="15" cols="100" name="g_description"></textarea><br><br>
            <input name="gfile" type="file" accept="image/*">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>
```

Так выглядит скрипт, обрабатывающий форму:

```
$destination = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/uploads/';
$fileTempName = $_FILES['gfile']['tmp_name'];
if (is_uploaded_file($fileTempName)) {
    $newFilename = $destination .$_FILES['gfile']['name'];

    //Перемещаем файл из временной папки в указанную
    if (move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $newFilename)) {
        echo 'Файл сохранен под именем '. $newFilename;
    } else {
        echo 'Не удалось осуществить сохранение файла';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Файл не был загружен на сервер';
}
```

Comment: Вы думаете тут телепаты? Поправьте вопрос, в котором будет явно видна ошибка и ваша проблема. Вопросы, мол просто не работает не работают

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); var_dump($_FILES['gfile']['error']);` в начало скрипта и выскочившие ошибки сюда.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример простейшей реализации

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['go'])){
        $err = array();#Массив с ошибками
        #Проверки
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"])){
            $err[] = "Ошибка загрузки файла";
        }
        if($_FILES["filename"]['error']!= 0){
            $err[] = 

"Ошибка загрузки файла";
        };
        if($_FILES["filename"]['size'] > 10485760){
            $err[] = "Файл слишком большой";
        };

if(count($err) == 0){
    //Если файл загружен успешно, то перемещаем в конечную директорию
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Files/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
} else{
    #Вывод ошибок проверок
    foreach($err AS $error){
        print $error."<br>";
    }
}
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filename" class="select_file"><br>
    <button name="go" class="login_button">Загрузить</button>
</form>
```